# How to get all messages of a specific number in Twilio using PHP API

Tags: php, api, twilio

I am using  - [PHP Library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/) of **Twilio** and want to grab all messages sent & received to a specific number?

I am new to this. Can any one guide/help me?

Comment: Have a look : https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms#list

Comment: Its deprecated and not working

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You want to use the [Messages list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) (you're right, the SMS resource is deprecated). You can pass in [filters for the To and From attributes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters) in order to get all the messages to that number.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Philnash, It seems i got what i wanted, let me try it out.

Comment: Yes It worked and i got this using CURL with post method along endpoint https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SID/Messages

Comment: That's great to hear! Good luck with whatever you're building.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out a easy way to grab all messages of a specific number using CURL

```
$base_url       =   "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SID/Messages?From=1112223333";  
$ch         =       curl_init($base_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$account_sid:$auth_token");

$response           =       curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$xml_array          =       new SimpleXMLElement($response);

echo "<pre>";   print_r($xml_array);    echo "</pre>";
```

Its 100% working example and you can get working all other functions by reading their updated docs at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message